# Create a HttpRequest instance in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have to create a `HttpRequest` instance with GET verb, and Uri, to pass the object to `OdataQueryOptions`.

Below is the sample code in c#. I need to convert in Dotnet core 3.1.

```
[EnableQuery]
   public class MyEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
    {
        public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
        {
            //IQueryable result = default(IQueryable);

            // get the original request before the alterations
            var originalRequest = queryOptions.Request.QueryString;

            // get the original URL before the alterations
            string url = originalRequest.Value;

            if (queryOptions.Filter != null && url.Contains("$filter=indexof%28Type,%27PRIMARY%27%29%20ne%20-1"))
            {
                url = url.Replace("$filter=indexof%28Type,%27PRIMARY%27%29%20ne%20-1", "$filter=indexof%28Type,%27toupper%28PRIMARY%28%27%29%20ne%20-1");
                //var context = new HttpContext()
                //HttpRequestMessageFeature request = new HttpRequestMessageFeature(context);
                //HttpRequestMessage req = request.HttpRequestMessage;

                queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryOptions.Context, Req);
            }

            return queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable, );
        }
    }
```

Below line gives error. It needs object of type `HttpRequest`.

```
queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryOptions.Context, Req);
```

Comment: You can convert it without HttpRequestMessage also, I m fine with that, basically I need to pass the request to ODataQueryOptions method so that it can execute the actual logic post attribute execution

Comment: updated the correct code

Answer (score 2):

`ODataQueryOptions` takes the ASP.NET request type `HttpRequest` which is available from `HttpContext.Request` in your controller.

```
[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts(ODataQueryOptions<Product> queryOptions)
{
    if (queryOptions.Filter != null)
    {
        queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions<Product>(
           queryOptions.Context, 
           HttpContext.Request); // here!!!
    }

    IQueryable query = queryOptions.ApplyTo(db.Products.AsQueryable());
    return query as IQueryable<Product>;
}
```